# Solving system of differential equations using matrix exponentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$x_1^{'} = 2x_1 + x_2$$
$$x_2^{'} = 2x_2$$

Since this is a non-diagonalizable matrix, I have no idea how to approach this problem. We have not learned the nilpotent, so I cannot use that to help me solve this. I derived the following:

$$A^{n}= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \lambda^{n}&n\lambda^{n-1}\\
      0&\lambda^{n}
    \end{array}
\right] $$

for

$$A= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \lambda&1\\
      0&\lambda
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you did ok in obtaining ${\bf A}^{\,n} $ . Now divide by $n!$ and sum, considering that $
{n \over {n!}}\lambda ^{\,n - 1}  = {1 \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}\lambda ^{\,n - 1} \;\left| {\,1 \le n} \right.$ (or that $
{n \over {n!}}\lambda ^{\,n - 1}  = {d \over {d\lambda }}{1 \over {n!}}\lambda ^{\,n} $)

Comment: @GCab Would you mind elaborating a little bit? I'm really lost.

Comment: @Moo I see that $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ make up the second column of the matrix exponential. When you do the expansion though, I get something like 
$I + \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      2t&1\\
      0&2t
    \end{array}
\right] + \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      (2t)^{2}&2(2t)\\
      0&(2t)^{2}
    \end{array}
\right] + \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      (2t)^{3}&3(2t)^{2}\\
      0&(2t)^{3}
    \end{array}
\right] ...$, in which case the diagonal for $e^{At}$ makes sense. The upper right hand corner is what's giving me trouble.